# Create and custom UITextfield inside Alertview in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, alert

I'm trying to create a large size textfield inside an alert view with a limit of 100 characters programatically. Here is my code:

```
func alertWithTF() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: Constants.cancelPopupTitle,
                                      message: Constants.cancelPopupMessage,
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 80)
            textField.placeholder = "Please enter message"
            textField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
            textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
            guard let textfield = alert?.textFields?.first else { return }
            let message = textfield.text ?? ""
            print(message)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is my problems:

- I wanted to modify textfield height by edit its frame but it seem not working.
- I also want to set the limit characters of textfield <= 100 but i wasn't able to find a way.

Is there any posible solutions that i can use? Thank for helping me.

Comment: There are lots of resource on how to limit text field to certain number of characters. Have you searched for it? Also, if you are going up to 100 characters wouldn't be better off using a text view?

Comment: Most of the resources tell me to use "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" but i'm not quite understand how it work out. And yeah, text view is seem to be more suitable for this case. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I understand it might be a little overwhelming in the begininning. I've been there myself. The key is to be patient and read a lot. Look at a lot of examples. Do a lot of POC's. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. UIAlertController is non-customizable. You can create your own alertViewController for this case and then play with UI however you want.
2. In your addTextfield, provide delegate to self

   ```
     alert.addTextField { (textField) in

       textField.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 80)
       textField.placeholder = "Please enter message"
       textField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
       textField.delegate = self
       textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
   }
   ```

And the you can use shouldChangeCharactersIn method to limit the length

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
let maxLimit = 180
let currentString = textField.text!
let newString: String =
    currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as String
return newString.length <= maxLength
}
```

make sure your ViewController conforms to UITextFieldDelegate.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer! I was about to create my own alertViewController if there no posible solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert.addTextField { textField in
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    textField.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```

Comment: This is limiting the height of the textField to `100pts`, not the character count inside the `textField`.

Answer (score 0):

So after several research my self, i have managed to implement this:

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func alertWithTF() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title",
                                      message: "\n\n\n\n\n",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.borderColor = .black
        textView.borderWidth = 1.0
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.text = Constants.textViewPlaceholder
        textView.textColor = .lightGray
        alert.view.addSubview(textView)

        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.topAnchor, constant: 125).isActive = true
        textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

        alert.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] (_) in
            self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] (_) in
            let message = (textView.text == nil||textView.text == Constants.textViewPlaceholder ? "" : textView.text)
            print(message)
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So i created a TextView instead of TextField and setup constraint for it inside alertView. These code was not perfect but it worked well. Also i used TextView delegate to handle textView characters limit anf placeholder since UITextView do not support it:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
        let numberOfChars = newText.count
        return numberOfChars < 101 //Max 100 chars
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            textView.text = ""
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text == "" {
            textView.text = Constants.textViewPlaceholder
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
```

Hope this is helpful!